# How to use split a string into character array without special characters?

Tags: java

```
    Scanner _in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an Equation of variables");
    String _string = _in.nextLine();


    char[] cArray = _string.toCharArray();
```

I want to remove the symbols "+,=" and I want to remove any repeating variables.

so far I have:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++){
   if(cArray[i].equals(+)|| cArray[i].equals(=)){
           cArray[i] = null;
        }

}
```

However, I dont know how to condence the array to remove any gaps and I don't know how to remove repeating characters, I think I am making this harder than it needs to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good use for [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/):

```
String result = _string.replaceAll("[+=]", "");
```

Here, the `[+=]` is a *character class* that consists of `+` and `=`. You can add other characters as required.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was about to type in.  Note taht it appears he's also wanting to remove commas

Comment: This one worked with the assignment statement. when I only did _string.replaceAll("[+=]", ""); the _string.toCharArray(); still contained + and = symbols

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
_string.replaceAll("[+,=]","");
```

Comment: No need to use \\ inside character class. Inside character class `+` also doesn't need to be escaped. `[+,=]` will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try the next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "a+a+b=c+d-a";

    char[] cArray = input.replaceAll("[-+=]", "")        // gaps
                         .replaceAll("(.)(?=.*\\1)", "") // repeating
                         .toCharArray();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cArray));
}
```

Output:

```
[b, c, d, a]
```

Comment: good solution @paul, but the result array is not in the same order of the original.

Comment: @omainegra: I dont't think so. The order is the same but he removes duplicates from the front...

Answer (score 0):

Or you can se another array, like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

String s = in.nextLine();
char [] cArray = s.toCharArray();

int count = 0;
char [] cArray2 = new char[cArray.length];

for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++){
    if (cArray[i] != '+' || cArray[i] != '='){
        cArray2[count++] = cArray[i];
    }
}


for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    boolean repeated = false;

    for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++){
        if (cArray2[i] == cArray2[j]){
            repeated = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!repeated){
        //do what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend LinkedHashSet (Which enforces uniqueness *and* retains order).  Override the add() function to not accept any characters that you don't want to use.  Then put the contents in a char array.

```
public static char[] toCharArray(String str) {

    // Here I am anonymously extending LinkedHashSet
    Set<Character> characters = new LinkedHashSet<Character>() {

        // Overriding the add method
        public boolean add(Character character) {
            if (!character.toString().matches("[\\+=]")) {
                // character is not '+' or '='
                return super.add(character);
            }
            // character is '+' or '='
            return false;
        }
    };

    // Adding characters from str to the set.
    // Duplicates, '+'s, and '='s will not be added.
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        characters.add(str.charAt(i));
    }

// Put Characters from set into a char[] and return.
    char[] arrayToReturn = new char[characters.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Character c : characters) {
        arrayToReturn[i++] = c;
    }
    return arrayToReturn;
}
```